# How do I wrap an element that has been cloned and appended?

Tags: jquery

I have no luck wrapping a link I cloned. The clone/append works fine.

```
var $becomelink = $('.welcome :contains("Become Owner")'); 
    if($becomelink.length > 0){  
       $('#menu ul.pureCssMenu').append($becomelink[0].cloneNode(true));
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$('$becomelink').wrap('<li class="new"></li>')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly jQuery has the `clone()` method, so you don't need to get the DOMElement from the jQuery object and use `cloneNode` on it. Secondly, `$becomelink` is a variable that contains your element in a jQuery object so you don't need to wrap it in another jQuery object, much less string delimiters. With that said, try this;

```
var $becomelink = $('.welcome :contains("Become Owner")'); 
if ($becomelink.length > 0) {  
    var $becomelinkClone = $becomelink.clone(true).wrap('<li class="new"></li>').parent();
    $('#menu ul.pureCssMenu').append($becomelinkClone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$becomelink is alread a jQuery object, so just `$becomeLink.wrap(...)` should suffice.