# clone element jQuery and add parent <tbody> before this element

Tags: jquery, html-table, tr, html-tbody

I have this element

```
<tr class="group-row">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

I want to clone it and add `<tbody>` parent to it to be like this

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="group-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: If you have a `table` element, then a `tbody` will already exist within it. Even if it's not set in your HTML, the browser renderer will add one as it's required to keep the HTML valid. Example of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9n1py843/. Inspect the DOM in the output to see that the `tbody` has been dynamically created for you.

Comment: i can agree with above, it might be helpfull to know **why** u would want to do this or what the initial problem is

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that, but I need to add this parent for a particular case

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone & https://api.jquery.com/wrap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I wrap an element that has been cloned and appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721918/how-do-i-wrap-an-element-that-has-been-cloned-and-appended)

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work :

```
var $clone = $("#element-to-clone").clone();
$("#where-you-want-to-put-the-clone").append($clone);
$clone.wrap( "<tbody></tbody>" );
```